# MSTeams bot - Set different bot name to display in chat window

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created an MSTeams bot, which is available on Teams App store. I want to change the bot name which is displayed in the chat window. Please refer the screenshot I attached below.

**Also similar to the configurable tabs in MSTeams, Is it possible, that the user who is installing the bot, change the name for his instance?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible to change these labels, but they need to be changed in different places. The one at the top (near where it says "Chat, "Files", etc. - let's call this "1") is part of your app manifest - where you tell Teams the name of your "App" inside Teams. The other two places (the item in the list of open Chats (2), and the label next to each message in the conversation (3)) are both managed inside the Azure portal, in your Bot registration, in the "Settings" page.

[Update: further info based on the comment below]

The name set in the manifest (1) can be changed if:

- you *allow* them to be changed - see "configurableProperties" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema, and
- they can be changed by the Teams admin for the tenant (in which case they will change for the *entire* tenant, not just a single user)

The name of the -bot- (2 & 3) can *only* be changed by you, and is the same for *all users* in *all tenants* (i.e. *anyone* who uses your bot) (I *really* wish this was changeable as well, at least per tenant!).

Comment: Thanks @hilton for your reply. Can you confirm about my second question. i.e. similar to the configurable tabs in MSTeams, Is it possible, that the user who is installing the bot, change the name for his instance?